# How to get all tr and td in a table that rows filtered by a attribute in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that include rows that any row has a attribute which called `entity-state`. I have get all `td` from rows that `entity-state !== 'deleted'`.

```html
<table>
    <tr entity-state="deleted"> 
        <td>1</td> 
        <td>2</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr entity-state="added"> 
        <td>3</td> 
        <td>4</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr entity-state="added"> 
        <td>5</td> 
        <td>6</td>  
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want get all `td` values that are in rows that `entity-state` is `added` only.

Comment: Note that `entity-state !== 'deleted'` and `entity-state='added'` may not provide the same result. It would help if you could specify exactly which you require.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the attribute selector for this:

```
$('tr[entity-state="added"]');
// or
// $('tr:not([entity-state="deleted"])');
```

You should note that `entity-state` is a non-standard attribute and will mean your HTML is invalid. To solve this you should use a `data-*` attribute instead:

```
<tr data-entity-state="deleted"> 
    <td>1</td> 
    <td>2</td> 
</tr>
<tr data-entity-state="added"> 
    <td>3</td> 
    <td>4</td> 
</tr>
```

```js
$('tr[data-entity-state="added"]');
```

It's also possible to achieve what you need using `filter()`, which is useful when using `data-*` attributes as changing their values through jQuery does not update the DOM.

```
var $enabledRows = $('tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('entity-state') == 'added';
    // or:
    // return $(this).data('entity-state') !== 'deleted';
});
```

Comment: Thanks,I'm testing now.

Comment: Attribute selector should be `[entity-state!=='deleted']` as per the requirement!

Comment: @Rayon From the OP: `I want get all td values that are in rows that entity-state is 'added' only.` It seems the OP needs to nail down exactly what's required, but it's a simple logic change either way

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Ooh sorry! I did not read that.. OP also said that _"I have get all td from rows that entity-state!=='deleted'"_

Answer (score 1):

You can use  combination of **[attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** and **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** (or **[`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not)**) selector

```
$('tr:not([entity-state="deleted"])')
```

or

```
$('tr').not('[entity-state="deleted"]')
```

```js
$('tr:not([entity-state="deleted"])')
  // or $('tr').not('[entity-state="deleted"]')
  .css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr entity-state="deleted">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr entity-state="added">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr entity-state="added">
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @MohsenZahedi : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('table tr[entity-state=added]').each(function(i,v){
var $td = $(this).find('td')

console.log($td.text())

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr entity-state="deleted">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr entity-state="added">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr entity-state="added">
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

1. Use the attr selector for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use not selector with attribute selector,

```
$("tr:not([entity-state='deleted']) td").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text())
});
```